# Is there a way to replicate np.random.rand() python function from C?

Tags: python, c, numpy, random, random-seed

I want to get random numbers in C sampled in the same way that np.random.rand() does ... the problem is that with rand()/srand() C functions I am not getting good results (random numbers from rand() C function seem to have some pattern).
Which is the best solution? call np.random.rand() from C ?

thanks

Comment: Can you provide your C code and show an example of the C function having some pattern? That shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Did you try to read the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html), in order to understand what random generation algorithm is actually used?

Comment: @Colin the C standard library `rand` is generally quite poor quality and the claim is very credible, at least depending on what math is applied to the raw values. AFAIK it's only guaranteed to offer 16 random bits, does not specify an algorithm, and will commonly use a simple LCG.

Comment: Windows: `BCryptGenRandom`, Linux: `RAND_bytes` (from OpenSSL).

Comment: Do you want the same numbers, given the same seed, or just numbers thst are statisticaly the same? Generally getting the same numbers with different languages (and computers) is impossible.

Comment: @hpaulj I am looking for number that  are statisticaly the same